# Magento 2 : Add to Cart Success Message in a Popup

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, popup, success-message

How can I show Add to Cart success message ("You added 'Product name' to your shopping cart.") in a popup in Magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

Copy **catalog-add-to-cart.js** from core '\module-catalog\view\frontend\web\js/catalog-add-to-cart.js and place into your theme folder \Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

Now find **ajaxSubmit** function and add below code after **self.enableAddToCartButton(form);**

```
var popup = $('<div class="add-to-cart-dialog"/>').html($('.page-title span').text() + '<span> has been added to cart.</span>').modal({ //get product name from product view page only
                    modalClass: 'add-to-cart-success-popup'
                });
                popup.modal('openModal');
```

Reference for more modal options: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

Answer (score 1):

copy and paste the `catalog-add-to-cart.js` file from `vendor\Magento\Catalog\view\frontend\Web\js` to `app\design\frontend\[NameSpace]\[Theme]\Magento_Catalog\web\js\catalog-add-to-cart.js`

with in that you have to modify `ajaxSubmit` function like below.

```
 ajaxSubmit: function(form) {
        var self = this;
        $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading');
        self.disableAddToCartButton(form);

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                    $('body').trigger(self.options.processStart);
                }
            },
            success: function(res) {
                if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                    $('body').trigger(self.options.processStop);
                }

                if (res.backUrl) {
                    window.location = res.backUrl;
                    return;
                }
                if (res.messages) {
                    $(self.options.messagesSelector).html(res.messages);
                }
                if (res.minicart) {
                    $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart);
                    $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
                }
                if (res.product && res.product.statusText) {
                    $(self.options.productStatusSelector)
                        .removeClass('available')
                        .addClass('unavailable')
                        .find('span')
                        .html(res.product.statusText);
                }
                alert("You added Product name to your shopping cart.");
                self.enableAddToCartButton(form);
            }
        });
    }
```

In `success` I have added below alert message.

```
alert("You added Product name to your shopping cart.");
```

After that fallow below steps.

1) Remove the `Magento_Catalog` folder from `pub\static\frontend\[NameSpace]\[Theme]\en_US\`

2) Run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme NameSpace/Theme`.

3) Open New browser and try to add product to cart above alert message will popup.

Like that you can customize it your way.

Comment: How can you replace "Product name" with the actual name of the product added?

Comment: @Jason Can you create a thread and describe briefly and tag me.